# "simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name" Error thrown on editing a module data in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I have a "**SOURCE**" module in laravel project. The edit functionality was working fine before I changed the DB. I added a column in **DB table "source"**. After adding it, whenever I try to edit the source data from admin panel, the data gets modified but shows the error: **simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name**
I am using API's in my project where I have used the function simplexml_load_string(). But this was working fine before I added a column to the DB. What could be a possible reason and solution for it?

Comment: Could be useful to show us how the string you are loading changed since the time it was working

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The issue was with my apache server version. To resolve the issue with the CURL extension of PHP, I installed Apache AddOn (Version - 2.4.28) to support PHP (>7.2) extensions. I downloaded the same from here - https://wampserver.aviatechno.net/ and install it at my end. Restart the Wamp Services and choose the updated version of Apache web server. And it was resolved.